# Segmentation Fault( Core Dumped) at the end of C program?

Tags: c, recursion, cs50

I just started learning C 4 days ago and am learning recursion atm using CS50 from HarvardX. So I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Please help me why I am getting this error.

I know that segmentation fault (Core Dumped) is mostly related to overflow memory? But I dont know why I am getting this error atm. I get it after the end of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void sort(int a[], int size);
int getMaxIndex(int a[], int size);


int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {};
    int index = -1;
    do
    {
        index++;

        a[index] = get_int("Enter a number(enter a -ve number to end): ");

    }
    while(a[index] >= 0);
    index--;
    sort(a, index);
    for(int i = 0; i<=index; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void sort(int a[], int size)
{
    int maxIndex, copy;

    if(size > 1)
    {
        maxIndex = getMaxIndex(a, size);
        copy = a[size];
        a[size] = a[maxIndex];
        a[maxIndex] = copy;
        sort(a, size - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

int getMaxIndex(int a[], int size)
{
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int max = a[maxIndex];
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(max < a[i])
        {
            max = a[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

Comment: The *FIRST* two things you need to do are 1) familiarize yourself with your debugger (for example: https://cs50.harvard.edu/ap/2020/assets/pdfs/bugs_and_debugging.pdf), then 2) reproduce the problem and get a stack trace.  This will show you exactly WHERE the problem occurred.  At which point you might have a fighting chance of understanding WHY it occurred.

Comment: `int a[] = {};` array is empty

Comment: Since `a` is an empty array, you're writing outside the array when you assign to `a[index]`. This causes undefined behavior, and segmentation faults are a common symptom.

Comment: "*array is empty*" the real problem is that the array is allocated for 0 elements. "Empty" might be interpreted differently by beginners.

Comment: To elaborate on the first comment: [Here](https://video.cs50.io/v_luodP_mfE?screen=J0ND72qsI9U&start=1688&end=2012) is the place in the CS50 video in which you are taught how to use CS50's debugger, which is called "debug50". With a debugger, you can run your program line by line while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to see in which line your program stops working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In constructing an [MCVE/SSCCE/whatever we call a minimal testcase](https://ideone.com/rDXA06) (source code below) I encountered a series of errors that explains part of the story, so let's look at those, first:

```
int main(void) {
    int a[] = {};
}
```

> prog.c:2:12: error: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Werror=pedantic]
> int a[] = {};

To start off this code isn't in good form because we're violating the standard. Therefore, if your compiler supports some extension here, technically that's undefined behaviour so you'll have zero legs to stand on if this kind of code brings you into court.

> prog.c:2:6: error: zero or negative size array ‘a’
> int a[] = {};

This is also necessary information, as it tells you what the capacity of that array is. You don't get resizable arrays like this in C; you can use VLAs (well, you can't for your solution, but they're suitable for some purposes), flexible array members (you need one of the `alloc` functions for this) or straight up pointers, like flexible array members but not binding the length to the allocation,  see below for example:

```
int *a = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
do
{
    int num = get_int("Enter a number(enter a -ve number to end): ");
    // XXX: you need to check that the user actually input a value somehow, and not garbage? I don't like CS50 for this very reason, it teaches very poor form
    
    // Now memorise the `realloc` idiom below (particularly storing the result in a `temp` variable):
    size_t index = size++;
    if ((index & size) == 0) {
        void *temp = realloc(a, (size+index) * sizeof *a);
        if (!temp) { // realloc fails sometimes...
            free(a);
            perror("realloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        a = temp;
    }

    a[index] = num;
} while (a[size - 1] >= 0);
```

This isn't recursive, but translating it into a recursive function isn't difficult. First we start with a function, named appropriately (`get_our_input` for example) and accepting pointers to `a` and `size`, for example:

```
int get_our_input(int **a, size_t *size) {
    // See snippets below for:
    // 1/ read input and error handling
    // 2/ reallocate and more error handling
    // 3/ assigning into the array and continuing the recursive loop
}
```

In that we need some code to read a number (with error handling ), something like:

```
    int num;
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {
        // When bad user input is encountered we need to manually discard it; I prefer to discard to the end of line
        char c;
        while (!feof(stdin) && fread(&c, 1, 1, stdin) == 1 && c != '\n');
        if (!feof(stdin)) return get_our_input(a, size);
        return 0;
    }
```

Then to "resize the array", as we so tend to erroneously say, we need this `realloc` idiom I mentioned earlier (it's nearly identical, see?):

```
    size_t index = *size++;
    if ((index & *size) == 0) {
        void *temp = realloc(*a, (index + *size) * sizeof **a);
        
        if (!temp) {
            // we let the caller handle cleanup
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        *a = temp;
    }
```

Then assigning the `num` into the array and completing the recursion will look something like:

```
    (*a)[index] = num;
    if (num >= 0) return get_our_input(a, size);
    return 0;
```

As far as `int getMaxIndex(int a[], int size)` goes, this can best be made recursive by `maxIndex` and `i` into arguments:

```
size_t getMaxIndex(int a[], size_t size, size_t maxIndex, size_t index)
{
    if (i >= size)
        return maxIndex;
    
    int max = a[maxIndex];
    if(max < a[i])
        return getMaxIndex(a, size, i, i+1);
    return getMaxIndex(a, size, maxIndex, i+1);
}
```